# Query Elasticsearch using String in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch maven jar file to query Elasticsearch. But now I want to query the elasticsearch using full generated query string:

query :

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "term" : {
        "title" : "mercedes"
      }
    }, {
      "term" : {
        "Doors" : "2"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

How do I use the above query string to query elasticsearch in java?

Answer (score 4):

Following code prepares a boolquery. You should create a `SearchRequestBuilder` to execute it.

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("title", "mercedes"));
boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("Doors", "2"));
```

If you want to use query as string without building it in code, you can use following;

```
String myQuery = "Your Query Here";
SearchSourceBuilder ssb= new SearchSourceBuilder();
search.query(myQuery);

SearchRequestBuilder srb; // You should define srb before next steps
srb.internalBuilder(ssb);
SearchResponse response = srb.execute().actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to query Elasticsearch using JSON string.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(yourIndexName)
            .setSource(yourJsonQueryString)
            .execute().actionGet();
```